# I want to store an int value before closing my UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

Is this possible to do without the use of sqlite database? Basically, I want to set the value of an int variable before I close the program, and when the program is restarted, the previously stored value should be displayed. I know I can do this using a text file and write the value to that file, and then retrieve the value from it. But is there a simpler way since this is just a number like 16340? Sorry, not much code here.

```
    private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        selectionIndex = 123;
        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

Comment: Anything you want/need to save after application is closed, needs to be saved somewhere. Beside database or a file (txt/xml/json or registry), there is no other way.

Comment: @Matt I see....

Answer (score 4):

If your program stops, every variable stored in the RAM memory will be killed along. The only way to persist a value is to write it to the Hard Disk Drive (or a USB key, or whatever device in the OS filesystem).

You have many ways to do so.
The simplest way is to write it down into a simple text file
But you can also store it into a database, as a registry key/value pair, as an application setting...
Anything that can be stored on the filesystem will do.

Comment: Agreed. @EsAMe If you want to know about a specific method, you should try searching on the internet first (there are tons of ressources for this sort of thing) and then ask a new question if you need help with something more specific.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to store this value is with the setting store.

Assuming you just want to store this locally on your machine:

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["selectionIndex"] = 123;
```

And when you restart your application, you can retrieve it:

```
// retrieve
object storedValue = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["selectionIndex"];

// check if it is null so you don't throw a null reference exception
if (storedValue != null)
    selectionIndex = (int) storedValue; // cast to int after you're sure it is not null.
```

This is great for small values (but it's recommended you still use a text file for very large data).

Answer (score 1):

Simple and short answer: No.

You are up to close the program. The OS will clear evertyhing out of the RAM. So you have to write it somewhere like a text file. There is no simpler way as writing the number in some textfile.

Comment: the OS does nothing to clear the RAM. It's the RAM itself losing its own memory due to it's nature

Comment: @phuclv depends how you look on it. If the device turns of then yes, the RAM clears itself since it can't hold it's data without electricity. If the application simply closes then no, the OS frees the RAM for other applications. Normally it should be nulled, so the new application cannot interpret the data of the other application due to security matters, but it's mostly not needed, since you can never be sure, which address the OS will assign to your programm for usage but you could use it.

Comment: I want to point out that `The OS will clear evertyhing [sic] out of the RAM` is wrong. It doesn't clear everything. It just clears the pages that were allocated to another application when it allocates those pages to another application. Obviously if it reassigns that same block to the same process then nothing will be cleared

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the resx file to store it? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/working-with-resx-files-programmatically